# Mustache render() over an array not working

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <script src="mustache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var musk = ["athos", "porthos", "some other guy"];

  var output = Mustache.render("<div>The three <br>{{#musk}}<p>{{.}}</p>{{/musk}}<br> Those guys</div>", musk);

  console.log(output);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This give me:

```
<div>The three <br><br> Those guys</div>
```

If I'm not mistaken, I'm copying the example from the github page almost identically.  Also, I'm pretty sure html is allowed inside the template, just not inside the content or view.  Right?

Comment: The musketeers are not complete without D'Artaganan !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to name the input array like this:

```
var musk = {musk: ["athos", "porthos", "some other guy"]};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Could I ask you to explain why?

Comment: If you don't name the array, how would the template engine now what you are referencing with {{#musk}} {{/musk}}. The variable name used in the function call is not visible to the engine.

Comment: hmmm...okay, gotcha!  So, my higher level problem is templating with data has many nested levels:

jsondata = {
  "title": "blog post title",
  "tags": ["fun", "cooking", "technical"]
};

I'll try and post a separate question for that.  Thanks so much!